# select and insert in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert some data in a table:

```
INSERT INTO match VALUES(null, CURDATE(), ID_LOCAL_TEAM, ID_VISITOR_TEAM, result, season)
```

But to insert ID_LOCAL_TEAM, i need to do another SELECT, from another table (coach table). The select is the next:

```
SELECT team FROM coach WHERE id_coach= SOME VALUE
```

The question is: how can I do this in the same query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: and ID_VISITOR_TEAM, result, season  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply combine the statements:

```
INSERT INTO match
SELECT
    NULL
,   CURDATE()
,   team AS ID_LOCAL_TEAM
,   ID_VISITOR_TEAM
,   result
,   season
FROM coach
WHERE id_coach = SOME_VALUE
```

As scaisEdge already asked, where are those other values in your INSERT statement coming from? If those are variables or strings, the above code should work fine. If they are selected from somewhere, you'll need to join whatever table they're from to the `coach` table.

The `AS ID_LOCAL_TEAM` isn't needed, just threw it in there as a reference point.

Comment: the answers in the post are good, but it's not what i need, probably i didn't explain well. What I need is to take the ID_LOCAL_TEAM from the coach table Where his id is SOME_VALUE, and put this id in the Insert. Probably this procedure is not what i'm lloking for

Comment: @zasaz - the query I provided is doing that. The SELECT statement is part of the INSERT.